# Deleting child entity in GAE datastore causes multiple entities being removed

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have one to many relationship within single entity group in GAE datastore implemented by 2 classes:

**User.java:**

```
public class User {
    ...
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "user", defaultFetchGroup="true")
    private List<Note> noteSets;
```

**Note.java:**

```
public class Note {
    ... 
    @Persistent
    private User user;
```

And I have following code to delete one Note by user key and note id:

```
public static void deleteNote(String userKey, long noteId) {
        PersistenceManager pm = DatastoreManager.get().getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            User user = pm.getObjectById(User.class, userKey);
            Key childKey = user.getUserKey().getChild(Note.class.getSimpleName(), noteId);
            Note note = pm.getObjectById(Note.class, childKey);
            pm.deletePersistent(note);
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }
```

This code works fine except for sometimes it removes more than 1 Note entity. What is the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: The issue was in update function. After update items in List<Note> noteSets were set with same id. It caused them to be deleted once at least one of them has been deleted.

Comment: please make this comment as answer to close the subject